# Understanding the Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

In an economics paper which has model written in continuous time, I came across a budget constraint showing stochastic evolution of wealth:

$$\mathrm{d}w_{t} = (r_{t}w_{t} + k_{t}\alpha_{t} - c_{t} - m_{t}i_{t})\mathrm{d}t + k_{t}\sigma\mathrm{d}W_{t}.$$

Here $w_{t}$  is total wealth, $r_{t}$ is return on wealth, $k_{t}$ is capital, $\alpha_{t}$ is excess return on capital, $c_{t}$ is consumption, $m_{t}$ is real money (nominal money divided by price level), $i_{t}$ is nominal interest rate rate, $\sigma$ is an idiosyncratic shock and $W_{t}$ is a Brownian Motion. When I first saw such equations, I tried to think if they could be written in usual $\frac{\mathrm{d}x_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} = a_{t} + b_{t} +h_{t}$ form which can then be recast as $\mathrm{d}x_{t} = (a_{t} + b_{t} + h_{t})\mathrm{d}t$ but apparently in the above case, it does not seem possible because of an additive term on the right hand side. What I exactly mean is, I reckon I cannot write the above equation as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} = r_{t}w_{t} + k_{t}\alpha_{t} - c_{t} - m_{t}i_{t}$$

since I will be missing the $k_{t}\sigma\mathrm{d}W_{t}$ term on the right hand side. And I think I cannot also write is as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} = r_{t}w_{t} + k_{t}\alpha_{t} - c_{t} - m_{t}i_{t} + k_{t}\sigma\mathrm{d}W_{t}$$

since in the original first equation, there is no $\mathrm{d}t$ term multiplying $k_{t}\sigma\mathrm{d}W_{t}$ on the right hand side.

Is there any way these equations can be written as usual differential equations like I just mentioned? What I am trying to do is to understand if there is some math here that I am missing. Am new to stochastic analysis. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you are missing some Ito Calculus. Have a look at Log normal SDE and how the solutions are formed from those. You have a difference that you have time dependence in the parameters, but you can leave in integral form.

Comment: Hi @Chinny84, thanks for your time. Could you please elaborate? I did look at [lognormal SDE] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) but I still wonder if the SDE in my question can be written as $\mathrm{d}x_{t} = (\text{something})\mathrm{d}t$ and if yes, how? Or it somehow is equivalent? Sorry, my stochastic analysis is rusty.

Comment: Just edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: Hi @Chinny84, any chance, you could please direct me to something which can help understand this issue? Will very much appreciate any hint/suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Chinny84, any chance you could look at the solution I posted and tell if it's indeed correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging around, I think I have found the answer. I am posting it here so that it might help somebody who may have the same question.

As written in [An Introduction to Computational Stochastic PDEs (page 314)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IO0E2TI) and [Oksendal's Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications, 6e (page 65)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BMTJ6WQ), a White Noise process in continuous time can be written as time derivative of a Brownian Motion, i.e.

$$\zeta(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}W_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

So the differential form of the SDE which represents the budget constraint in the question is

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} = r_{t}w_{t} + k_{t}\alpha_{t} - c_{t} - m_{t}i_{t} + k_{t}\sigma\frac{\mathrm{d}W_{t}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

where the last additive term contains a White Noise shock (which is time derivative of Brownian Motion) to capital. Multiplying both sides by $\mathrm{d}t$, one gets the following differential form:

$$\mathrm{d}w_{t} = (r_{t}w_{t} + k_{t}\alpha_{t} - c_{t} - m_{t}i_{t})\mathrm{d}t + k_{t}\sigma\mathrm{d}W_{t}$$